# Plotting nested lists seperately, which are inside nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list consisting of multiple nested dictionaries and nested lists

```
MyList = [{dict0}, {dict1}, {dict2} ... {dict2422}]

dict0 = {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[1, 2], [1, 2], [ [3, 4], [3, 4]]]}}
dict1 = {'type': 'Feature', 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[1, 2], [1, 2], [ [3, 4], [3, 4]]]}}
```

I have tried the following by help from comments:

```
coords = sum((x['coordinates'] for item in features if 'coordinates' in (x :=item.get('geometry',{}))),start=[])
```

which results in:

```
coords = [[[1, 2], [1, 2]],
          [[3, 4], [3, 4]],
          [[5, 6], [5, 6]]]
```

I want to plot these lists seperately from eachother so:

```
coords1 = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
coords2 = [[3, 4], [3, 4]]
coords3 = [[5, 6], [5, 6]]
```

and then plotting the first row of `coords1` as x coordinate, second row as y coordinate. And then do the same for coords2.
The entire `coords` list consists of ~2244 lists like this, each list of seperate landmass coastline xy coordinates, so `coords1` is landmass 1, which is why the `coords1` and `coords2` need to be plottet independently

I tried to combine all the first elements of each lists and second elemnts of each lists to each their own new list

```
flatlist = [el for lst1 in coords for lst2 in lst1 for el in lst2]
x, y = flatlist[0::2], flatlist[1::2]
```

But plotting this just gives connecting lines between landmasses coastlines as its just 2 long lists of coordinates.

So how do I seperate the original `coords`list into multiple lists, `coords1`, `coords2`, `coords3` and so fourth, and then plot it? I know simple plots, but the `coords` has ~2244 lists in it and don't how to plot it without making 2244 lines of code. I assume a looped plot but I don't know how to. The `coords` list does not need to be seperated if plotting directly from it is possible.

Comment: You can fix your post by [edit]ing it

Comment: okay I edited the entire post, I think I have done a better job at explaining it now, thank you.

Comment: You're almost there, but your initial dictionary is still not valid python. Please make sure you can paste your code into a new console and it runs as you describe.

Comment: Take a look at the brackets in your first snippet. I think you're missing something. What do you mean by "plot separately"? You won't be able to do that with a single one-liner most likely.

Comment: oh yeah I see, weird since I copied it in, fixed. I mean they are all to be plotted in on the same plot, but as each set of lists consists of coordinates corresponding to continents, each set of list is to be plotteted separately from each other, but on the same plot.

Comment: What's stopping you from plotting each element of the result list? You're still not clearly explaining the problem. Also, how is `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]` to be used?

Comment: What is stopping me is my python knowledge, I don't know how to seperate the,  `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]` and `[[3, 4], [3, 4]]` and `[[5, 6], [5, 6]]` from the original grouped list of `[[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[3, 4], [3,4]], [[5, 6], [5,6]]].

Comment: How would you plot a single list? Your question is changing, which indicates that you haven't quite figured out what you actually want to ask yet

Comment: I would plot the single list as 
`flatlist = [el for lst1 in coords for lst2 in lst1 for el in lst2]`

`x_coordinate, y_coordinate = flatlist[0::2], flatlist[1::2]`

Comment: I have big list with xy coordinates of coastlines of different landmasses, `coords`. These different landmasses xy coordinates are in seperate list inside `coords`, and I cannot just combine them all to a flatlist and plot first row as x and second row as y as that would make lines between coastlines. I need to plot the xy coordinates of each landmass seperately from eachother, so get first row of all lists in landmass 1 coordinates x, second row y and plot it. Then do the same untill I reach landmass 2244. 
I know what I want to ask, but bad at explaining it. Sorry, english is not first lang

Comment: English is not the issue here. Please edit your question (and title) to explain. You showed the inputs, but you are not happy about the outputs. The list I gave you will allow you to plot (in a loop). You have to explain why it's not working.

Comment: okay will try and do, but how to plot in loop?

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you are looking for,

```
a=[]
b=[]
for dic in MyList:
    for i in range(len(dic["geometry"]["coordinates"])):
        a.append(dic["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][0])
        b.append(dic["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][1])
```

Comment: Close, but sadly not exactly. This one takes, for each dict in MyList, goes to ['geometry'] -> ['coordinates'] and appends the first list/row of coordinates in the list coordinates to x, and second list/row to y, but skips those after.

The dict key 'coordinates' is a list size 1 containing a variable list size depending on which dict you access. Eg. key 'coordinates' contains a list size 1, which contains a list size 15 with each list containing x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
coords = sum((item['geometry']['coordinates'] for item in MyList), start=[])
```

A "safe" version would be

```
coords = sum((x['coordinates'] for item in MyList if 'coordinates' in (x := item.get('geometry', {}))), start=[])
```

The standard idiom for transposing a list afterwards is

```
x, y = zip(*coords)
```

Comment: This is almost it, it outputs a list containing the corresponding list of variable amount of coordinates to each dict from MyList.
`x, y = zip(*coords)`
did not work due to error **Too many values to unpack** (coords = list of 2422 elements)

Comment: @JonProbstGulfeldt. Tell you what, you post an actual [mcve] with 3-4 dicts containing 2-3 coordinates each, as well as an expected output, and I'll fix my answer to match.

Comment: I will try and do that thanks, sorry it was my first post :/